# I keep getting this bad input error for my if statement

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have everything defined but I am still getting a syntax error in this statement, any idea what I am doing wrong?
screenshot of code
[image: 1]

```
#add collision
if (car.xcor() + 10 = dog.xcor() and car.ycor() + 10 = dog.ycor()):
  dog.clear()
else:
  pass
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison.

Comment: Side note: `else: pass` is useless and not needed here. It is ok to have an `if` without an `else`.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin this is best flagged as "not reproducible / caused by typo", as opposed to as a duplicate, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to understand the "=" operator.

A single "=" is an **assignment**. You're giving a value to a variable.

```
x = 3
print(x)
>>>> 3
```

A double "==" is a **comparison**. You're comparing two objects.

```
3 == 3
>>>> True
```

In your case, you are trying to make a **comparison**. I have not seen the classes that you have created, but at least the first line should be altered to:

```
if ((car.xcor()+10) == dog.xcor()) and ((car.ycor()+10) == dog.ycor()):
```

Please notice, I have used excessive parenthesis, because I believe they make it easier to read.

Comment: That got rid of the syntax error, but it does not clear when it it true

Comment: After an "if" statement you need something that will be interpreted as True/False. You cannot add an assignment just after an if statement.

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this, what would I add to make the code interpret it as true or false?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to make comparisons right?

Use '==' which is the assignment operator instead of simply '='. The assignment operator will evaluate your condition and since the operator outputs a boolean(true or false) value, hence your code would work fine.

Secondly, there was indentation error as well which I have corrected. Check for the indentation in your code. You can use 'tab' key to adjust indentation. And the use parenthesis makes your code more readable.

```
if (car.xcor() + 10 == dog.xcor()) and (car.ycor() + 10 == dog.ycor()):
    dog.clear()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks I don't get the error anymore, but I am trying to make it happen when they "collide" and nothing happens, any advice?

Comment: Yes, happy to help! Could you elaborate more please? What do you mean by 'collide here'?

Comment: So I am trying to make a game where a car drives around and collects coins put on the screen, and I've been trying to code it so that when the car drives close to the coin, the coin disappear and another one appears in a random position. I got the coin to place and to appear in a random position, but could not get the coin to disappear when collided.